# SimpleXMLElement get non-attribute values

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have the following SimpleXMLElement:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (3) { 
    ["@attributes"]=> array(3) { 
        ["id"]=> string(8) "18022352" 
        ["name"]=> string(14) "The Salmon Man" 
        ["slug"]=> string(14) "the-salmon-man" 
    } 

    ["bids"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) { 
        ["price"]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(4) { 
                                ["decimal"]=> string(4) "9.60" 
                                ["percent"]=> string(5) "10.42" 
                                ["backers_stake"]=> string(5) "40.36" 
                                ["liability"]=> string(6) "347.00" 
                        } 
                 } 
        } 
    } 

    ["offers"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) { 
        ["price"]=> array(1) { 
                [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#15 (1) { 
                        ["@attributes"]=> array(4) { 
                                ["decimal"]=> string(4) "9.20" 
                                ["percent"]=> string(5) "10.87" 
                                ["backers_stake"]=> string(5) "85.35"         
                                ["liability"]=> string(5) "10.41" 
                        } 
                }  
        } 
    }
}
```

Why does this work:

```
$horse[0]['name']
```

but this doesn't:

```
$horse[0]['bids'] // also tried $horse['bids'] and other ways
```

I can get the values like below but I was hoping to search the smaller object:

```
$xml->xpath("//odds/event[@id='$matchid']/market[@slug='to-win']/contract[@name='$pony']/bids"); // $pony == $horse[0]['name']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's often easier to look at the XML itself, rather than a `print_r` of the SimpleXML object. In this case, you have something like this:

```
<horse id="18022352" name="The Salmon Man" slug="the-salmon-man">
    <bids>
         <price decimal="9.60" percent="10.42" backers_stake="40.36" liability="347.00" />
    </bids>
    <offers>
         <price decimal="9.60" percent="10.42" backers_stake="40.36" liability="347.00" />
    </offers>
</horse>
```

The `bids` item is an *element*, and as discussed in [the SimpleXML Basic Usage guide](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), you access child elements with `->foo` notation, whereas attributes use `['foo']` notation.

So if `$horse` is that `<horse>` element, you need:

```
$name = $horse['name'];
$bids = $horse->bids;
```

Note that this is equivalent to explicitly asking for the *first* child called `bids`; both forms will work regardless of whether there is actually more than one identically name element:

```
$bids = $horse->bids[0];
```

Now there are presumably one or more `<price>` elements in practice, so you might want to loop over, and then echo each `decimal` attribute. That would look like this:

```
foreach ( $horse->bids->price as $price ) {
    echo $price['decimal'];  
}
```

Again, this loop will work fine with only one `<price>`, it will just just loop once. If there is only ever one price, or you only care about the first one, you could just write:

```
echo $horse->bids->price['decimal'];
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
echo $horse->bids[0]->price[0]['decimal'];
```

Or of course either of these:

```
echo $horse->bids[0]->price['decimal'];
echo $horse->bids->price[0]['decimal'];
```

The number of different ways of getting to the same place is one reason I don't recommend relying too much on `print_r` output. Another is that it sometimes can't display everything that's in the XML, *which doesn't mean that data isn't available if you ask for it*.